2D scipy.optimize.curve_fit using a 1D approach
My goal is to achieve a two dimensional curve fit using scipy curve_fit function (I'm a bit lazy and just wanted to apply my typical 1D curve fitting to a 2D surface).
I begin with two lambda functions. The first describes the two-dimensional surface with variables X,Y and parameters P; lambda1(X, Y, P). The second lambda function "wraps" the first lambda so I can use it on 1D arrays,  lambda2(index, P) =  lambda1(x[index], y[index], P). I then write 3 two-dimensional matrix: XX, YY, ZZ matrix, which I reshape into three one-dimensional arrays: x_line, y_line, z_line.
The lambda function seems well behaved, as I can create a two dimensional surface when I call on lambda2 and reshape its output into the proper form. However when I call curve_fit to find the optimal parameters I run into an error prompt:
sag_eq_wrapped = lambda index, x0, y0, z0, r, k: ((1/r)*((x_line[index]-x0)**2+(y_line[index]-y0)**2)**2) / (1+np.sqrt(1-(1+k)*(1/r)**2*((x_line[index]-x0)**2+(y_line[index]-y0)**2))) + z0
                                                              ~~~~~~^^^^^^^
IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Is there away around this error? I have used lambda functions in curve_fit before but this is the first time I tried this wrapping method and call on other arrays in the lambda function. Maybe it just doesn't behave well with the curve_fit function...
Thanks for the help.
below is the example code:
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

###Define Lanbda function for Surface
sag_eq = lambda x, y, x0, y0, z0, r, k: ((1/r)*((x-x0)**2+(y-y0)**2)**2) / (1+np.sqrt(1-(1+k)*(1/r)**2*((x-x0)**2+(y-y0)**2))) + z0
sag_eq_wrapped = lambda index, x0, y0, z0, r, k: ((1/r)*((x_line[index]-x0)**2+(y_line[index]-y0)**2)**2) / (1+np.sqrt(1-(1+k)*(1/r)**2*((x_line[index]-x0)**2+(y_line[index]-y0)**2))) + z0

###Make Image and Domain
x_dom = np.linspace(0,0.32, 2**8)
y_dom = np.linspace(0,0.24, 2**7)
param = [x_dom[-1]/2, y_dom[-1]/2, 0, -0.2, -1]
zz = []
for y in y_dom:
    base = sag_eq(x_dom, y, param[0], param[1], param[2], param[3], param[4])
    noise = np.random.rand(len(base))
    zz.append(base+noise*1e-3)

###Make the two-dimnesional Data
zz=np.array(zz)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_dom, y_dom)

###Make wrapped 1Dimnesional arrays
x_line = xx.reshape(len(x_dom)*len(y_dom))
y_line = yy.reshape(len(x_dom)*len(y_dom))
z_line = zz.reshape(len(x_dom)*len(y_dom))
index_line = np.arange(0, len(x_dom)*len(y_dom), dtype=int)

###Make surface using wrapped Lambda function
surface_1 = sag_eq_wrapped(index_line, param[0], param[1], param[2], param[3], param[4])
surface_1 = surface_1.reshape(len(y_dom), len(x_dom))

fig, [ax_data, ax_surf1] = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax_data.contourf(xx, yy, zz); ax_data.set_title("Data Surf")
ax_surf1.contourf(xx, yy, surface_1); ax_surf1.set_title("lamda made Surf")
plt.show()

fig, [ax_x, ax_y] = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax_x.scatter(x_line, z_line); ax_x.set_title("Wrapped X Data")
ax_y.scatter(y_line, z_line); ax_y.set_title("Wrapped Y Data")
plt.show()


popt, pcov = curve_fit(sag_eq_wrapped, index_line, z_line, p0 = param)



I was expecting Curve_fit to work as normal. Unfortunately I do not completely understand the error prompt as the elements in index_line are of type int

The method curve_fit can fit multiple independent variables function. All you need is to fulfill the objective function signature.
The given model has correct signature:
def model(x, x0, y0, z0, r, k):
    return ((1 / r) * ((x[0] - x0) ** 2 + (x[1] - y0) **2) **2) / (1 + np.sqrt(1 - (1 + k) * (1/r) ** 2 * ((x[0] - x0) ** 2 + (x[1] - y0) ** 2))) + z0

We can use it to fit your dataset:
popt, pcov = optimize.curve_fit(model, [x_line, y_line], z_line, p0=[0.2, 0.2, 0., -0.1, -1])
#(array([ 1.59933408e-01,  1.20135077e-01,  4.99474227e-04, -1.98327589e-01,
#         -1.05312362e+00]),
# array([[ 6.23363842e-09, -9.67064719e-14, -9.17427476e-14,
#         -2.12181236e-10,  7.81917668e-09],
#        [-9.67064719e-14,  1.40063897e-08,  2.09623759e-13,
#          2.83771229e-10, -1.24165280e-08],
#        [-9.17427476e-14,  2.09623759e-13,  7.59814526e-12,
#          4.16322029e-09, -9.09518272e-08],
#        [-2.12181236e-10,  2.83771229e-10,  4.16322029e-09,
#          4.35907326e-06, -1.07458297e-04],
#        [ 7.81917668e-09, -1.24165280e-08, -9.09518272e-08,
#         -1.07458297e-04,  2.77570575e-03]]))

And regress the function:
zhat = model([x_line, y_line], *popt)

Graphically it leads to:
fig, axe = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
axe.scatter(x_line, y_line, z_line, marker=".", alpha=0.15)
axe.plot_surface(xx, yy, zhat.reshape(xx.shape), cmap="jet")


